# Resize window calls paintComponent each time Window is resized?

Tags: java, swing

Why does the paintComponent update everytime I resize the Window?

This is the class that I'm adding to a JPanel that adds to a JFrame. Is the object being called each time the window is re-sized or what is exactly happening with the paint component?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class DrawString extends JPanel {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 10);
        g2.setFont(font);
        g2.drawString("Test string",randInt(1,1000), randInt(1, 1000)); 

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            g.setColor(new Color(randInt(1,255), randInt(1,255),randInt(1,255)));
            g.drawLine(randInt(1,1000), randInt(1,1000), randInt(1,1000), randInt(1,1000));
        }
    }
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.paintComponent(g);
        super.setBackground(new Color(100,100,100));
        paint(g);
    }
    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

        // Usually this can be a field rather than a method variable
        Random rand = new Random();

        // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
        // so add 1 to make it inclusive
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        return randomNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: When a window resizes, `paintComponent()` is called to give the window a change to adapt to it's new size. If you compute something every frame, you should do that in a separate method you call before you call `repaint()`, so if `paintComponent()` because of a resize you won't have an extra frame.

Comment: Why _shouldn't_ `paintComponent` get called when you change the window dimensions? You're changing the amount of space to paint _into_, either clipping away part of the window or adding more space to draw. If you're using a layout manager, your components would also likely move and/or resize with the window, so they would need to be drawn differently, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what happens when you combine model with view. Never combine displaying gui/graphics with your internal app logic. These are logically separate and should remain like this.

But to answer your question: you have no control over when `paintComponent()` is called. Even calling repaint is nothing less than a *suggestion* to java's GUI that it should repaint the component.

And yes, in most cases resizing will cause a `paintComponent()` call.

Answer (score 1):

By resizing the window you have changed the window's properties, so your view elements should be painted again. I think this is reasonable, as graphical property changes of your display layout should trigger the paintComponent to allow your window to adapt to the changes.